# How can I scape a double qoutes inside a django tag?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I would like to escape the these quotes "d-m-Y" in the code below. How can I escape these quotes, they make my project crash.

```js
                                    <td><a href="{% url 'tender_list' date='{{ tenderEnquiries.d_assigned|date:"d-m-Y" }}' %}">{{ tenderEnquiries.c }} tenders</a></td>
```

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel has the correct cause, but the solution is much simpler; just remove the inner template tag completely, along with the quotes.

```
{% url 'tender_list' date=tenderEnquiries.d_assigned|date:"d-m-Y" %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. And thank you to you too Daniel Hepper, your answer taught me a few things I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not the problem. The problem is that you try to nest a template tag inside a template tag, which the Django template language does not support.

You have several options:

- pass the equivalent of `tenderEnquiries.d_assigned|date:"d-m-Y"` as a template variable and use it to reverse the URL
- reverse the URL in your view and pass it as a template variable
- create a custom template tag that receives `tenderEnquiries` as a parameter and renders the URL